# Returning array count + 1 for tableview cells

Tags: swift, tableview

I've been struggling with this problem for quite a while and can't seem to find a solution. I've searched for days and haven't been able to find a relatable answer either.

I have a few different view controllers and each have a tableview inside of them. A function is executed that populates various arrays and those arrays are used to populate the tableview cells.

My issue is that each table view has a cell at indexPath 0 that serves as header information with some images and some text. Below that cell is dynamic content generated from the arrays.

Everything works fine with populating the table with the data from the arrays but when I'm returning the array count for numberOfRowsInSection one of the rows isn't displayed since I have the header cell at indexPath 0.

I've tried appending a +1 to the end of the count but it returns an error (index out of range).

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like I've been very close to resolving the issue but can't seem to complete it. The code for my tableview count isn't anything special, nor is the implementation of the data.

eventImages is a PFFile array

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return eventImages.count
}
```

Comment: Why not use the section header function available with uitableviewdelegate instead of faking it with a cell? viewForHeaderInSection or something.

Comment: That was my initial idea when I wanted to lay the table out. I haven't had much experience using the header function outside of basic text. Pardon my beginner question but does the actual header have any limitations in comparison to a normal cell?

Comment: No limitations. The function returns a uiview so you can do whatever you want with it. Search for viewForHeaderInSection and you should find some examples.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want to do it by having an extra row, that can be done too.  As you said, return `count + 1` but then when providing a cell for the index path check if it's row 0 and do something special.  If it's not 0, subtract one from the row and use that to access your array.

Comment: No problem. You will also need to implement heightForHeaderInSection as well to make it work properly.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I'm not able to layout any elements in the storyboard for the header. It's only allowing me to place one element in there.